# Need a custom registration plugin/script for Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress, wpmu

I'm looking for a plugin or a code that can let me customize the registration-form on Wordpress multisite (/wp-signup.php).

What I would like to be able to do is to add the choise to set password and maybe add some fields like "City"

Can someone help me with this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one. It solved my problem

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/set-password-on-wordpress-mu-blog-creation